# Are these clauses identical?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at a javascript that my colleague wrote and I think that it looks like it does the same in both clauses:

```
function doSubmitOversikt(action, command, status) {

    var checked = document.getElementById("klarbox").checked;

    if(status && !checked) {

        if (confirm("Ärendet är satt som Klar (formell handläggning första delen klar). Vill du verkligen ångra detta? Att ångra kan innebära att ärendet behöver arras om i CICS.")) {

            document.actionForm.action.value = action;
            document.actionForm.actionCommand.value = command;  
            document.actionForm.submit();
            disableAll();

        }
    } else {

        document.actionForm.action.value = action;
        document.actionForm.actionCommand.value = command;  
        document.actionForm.submit();
        disableAll();
    }

}
```

What will be the difference between the above code and to unconditionally do

```
    document.actionForm.action.value = action;
    document.actionForm.actionCommand.value = command;  
    document.actionForm.submit();
    disableAll();
```

?

Comment: If `status == true`, `checked == false` and the `confirm()` dialog is canceled, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No not the same. If  both `status` and `!checked` evaluate to true, BUT the user doesn't confirm. nothing happens.

However note that it violates the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) when doing it like that.

Comment: Ok now I see. I'm going to rewrite to a more appropriate form. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first loop will only execute if the confirmation is positive; and if the checkbox is not checked and `status` is a true value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they are one condition is if status is true and it's not checked then asked for confirmation else do nothing.  If status is not true or it is checked then do.